# Connecting 4 tables - finding some differences between them

Tags: oracle

I have 4 tables in a Oracle database:

SOL_PUBLIC.SOL_CHEST@RACDB (PUB):

```
ID     ...
100    ...
200    ...
300    ...
```

SOL_PUBLIC.COORD@RACDB (PUB):

```
ID FK_ID_CHEST  x  y
1  100          11 11
2  200          22 22
3  300          33 33
```

SOL_CHEST (PROD)

```
ID     ...
100    ...
200    ...
300    ...
```

SIM_SOL.COORD (PROD)

```
ID FK_ID_CHEST  x  y
1  100          11 11
```

so, some rows are missing from PROD part.
I want to get all rows missing from PROD.COORD table that are in PUB.COORD table.

I first tried to get all 4 tables "in the same place"

```
select *
    from SOL_CHEST PROD,
        SOL_PUBLIC.SOL_CHEST@RACDB PUB
    inner join SOL_PUBLIC.COORD@RACDB coord_pub 
        on coord_pub.FK_ID_CHEST=PUB.ID
    inner join SIM_SOL.COORD coord_prod
        on coord_prod.FK_ID_CHEST=PROD.ID
```

but it gives me

```
[Error] Execution (67: 40): ORA-00904: "PROD"."ID": invalid identifier
```

how to do this (connecting the 4 tables and get the rows missing from prod.coord that are in pub.coord)
Thanks!

Comment: your query uses SOL_CHEST but you haven't mentioned this table in your  question

Comment: I correct that, sorry... the tables are more complex but I tried to simplify them for the example.

Comment: your inner join construct contains an on clause with 'PROD.ID' but your inner join tables are PUB, coord_pub and coord_prod, but no PROD table. The prod table will be available in a where clause (which is not present in this query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to join all 4 tables, this will show the missing rows

```
select id, fk_id_chest, x, y from SOL_PUBLIC.COORD@RACDB
minus
select id, fk_id_chest, x, y from SIM_SOL.COORD
```

Comment: this query also shows rows with same id but different x,y or fk_id_chest values, these are rows that differ but not rows that are missing.. I think the question needs some clarification.

Comment: i was just going by the example data which implies all the data columns will be the same (when the row is there). But, yes a bit more clarification wouldn't hurt

Comment: In that case you've only need to extend the query for your needs

`select id, fk_id_chest, x, y from SOL_PUBLIC.COORD@RACDB
minus
select id, fk_id_chest, x, y from SIM_SOL.COORD where id not in (select id from SOL_PUBLIC.COORD@RACDB)`